# Is there something in Python similar to quantstrat in R?

Tags: python, r, quantitative-finance, quantstrat

Is there something in Python similar to [quantstrat](http://www.r-bloggers.com/?s=quantstrat) in R?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, [Quantopian](https://www.quantopian.com) uses an open-source Python backtesting engine called [zipline](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline).